# Trying to do store locator with MySQL, PHP and Google Maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm trying to install a page into my mobile and web application with a Google map, pulling the co-ordinates from MySQL database using PHP. I've tried to tutorials, one putting the information into XML and the other into JSON.
However, neither tutorial, including their tables, are returning ANY information to me whatsoever.
I've even tried the code for non PHP5 even. The most I have returned is

```
<markers>
</markers>
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

The 2 tutorials I've followed are;

- [theoryapp](http://theoryapp.com/online-store-locator-using-php-mysql-and-google-maps/)
- [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=de)

Thanks in advance
Paula

JSON Code

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$db = '';

function die_with_error($error) {
$ret = array(
    "status" => "Failed",
    "error" => $error
);
die(json_encode($ret));
}

$center_lat = ( isset( $_GET["lat"] ) ? $_GET["lat"] : 37 ); # You could replace these "0"s with the
$center_lng = ( isset( $_GET["lng"] ) ? $_GET["lng"] : -122 ); # Lat/Lng of a default location.
$radius     = ( isset( $_GET["radius"] ) ? $_GET["radius"] : 10 ); # Again, default
if (!$center_lat || !$center_lng)
die_with_error("invalid parameters");


mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
or die_with_error(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die_with_error(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) *                  cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers      HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (! $result)  
die_with_error(mysql_error()); 
$result_array = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
array_push($result_array, array(
    "lat" => $row['lat'],
    "lng" => $row['lng'],
    "address" => $row['address'],
    "distance" => $row['distance']
    ));
}

$ret = array(
"status" => "OK",
"data" => $result_array);
die(json_encode($ret));
?>
```

For XML it was

```
function parseToXML($htmlStr)  
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 
$center_lat = ( isset( $_GET["lat"] ) ? $_GET["lat"] : 37 ); # You could replace these "0"s with the
$center_lng = ( isset( $_GET["lng"] ) ? $_GET["lng"] : -122 ); # Lat/Lng of a default location.
$radius     = ( isset( $_GET["radius"] ) ? $_GET["radius"] : 10 ); # Again, default

$connection=mysql_connect ('mysql2017int.cp.blacknight.com', $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$connection) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT 'address', 'name', 'lat', 'lng', ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( 'lat' ) ) * cos( radians( 'lng' ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( 'lat' ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<markers>\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<marker ';
echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
echo 'distance="' . $row['distance'] . '" ';
echo "/>\n";
}

echo "</markers>\n";
```

Comment: It would be quite helpful to see your code.

Comment: There you go xd6_ Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you removed all the DB info for the posting. Have you tried echo'ing the $query to ensure it's being built correctly? It also helps to copy it and test it directly through your DB backend (often phpMyAdmin) to make sure the query itself is forming correctly.

Comment: How are you querying your PHP when you get the empty `<markers></markers>` response?  Do you have any markers within a 10 mile radius of 37.0,-122.0?

Comment: Yes I removed DB details for the post. Tried running the query directly in the DB but it doesn't recognise the %s. And yes, all table entries are within those markers so it should display 5-10 results @xd6_ and geocodezip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius provided in the tutorial is not enough. If you increase it to 25000 instead of 25, it works.

Hopefully this might help anyone else in the future.